# Use Java to convert JSON to rdf documents with .xml suffix

Tags: java

There are very few examples on the Internet, or the versions are incompatible, and the method reports an error. I have java8, java11, java17, and I don’t know how to use rdf4j

I want a simple example that is compatible with various versions of Java, without the need for huge and complicated jar packages

Comment: *"and the method reports an error*" - whats the error? also, have you checked [tag:jena]?

Comment: Open source projects found from github

Comment: hi yongliang, it would be nice if you could provide a [mcve] to work with. its kind of hard to give concrete suggestion given the state of your question. i do curious whether you have checked [ask] and took a [tour] yet. those material can help you formulate the question better. we can't help you unless you help us to understand the problem better..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2017/CIM-Schema-cim17#" xmlns:md="http://iec.ch/TC57/61970-552/ModelDescription/1#" xmlns:sgsei="http://epri.sgcc.com.cn/sgsei">
<cim:RemoteUnit rdf:ID="08000000301-00000000003802726935595852084">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:PowerSystemResource.PSRType rdf:resource="0408003"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.remoteUnitType rdf:resource="http://iec.ch/TC57/2017CIM-Schema-cim17#RemoteUnitType.X"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#2tTcY3W0eYW0fKNvlny1tU"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#rPvX1ee3to6MW2M2uE7sNU"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#qxB2S9mcOIun9JbjczHdEU"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#ArzBZyFrvoWf2ck2Hluuqk"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-2tTcY3W0eYW0fKNvlny1tU"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-ArzBZyFrvoWf2ck2Hluuqk"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-qxB2S9mcOIun9JbjczHdEU"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-rPvX1ee3to6MW2M2uE7sNU"/>
</cim:RemoteUnit>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-2tTcY3W0eYW0fKNvlny1tU">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
<cim:RemoteUnit rdf:ID="08000000301-00000000003802726935595851640">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:PowerSystemResource.PSRType rdf:resource="0408003"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.remoteUnitType rdf:resource="http://iec.ch/TC57/2017CIM-Schema-cim17#RemoteUnitType.X"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.CommunicationLinks rdf:resource="0"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#30500000-39837314"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#30500000-39837340"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#30500000-39837339"/>
<sgsei:RemoteUnit.Equipment rdf:resource="#30500000-39837329"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-30500000-39837314"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-30500000-39837329"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-30500000-39837339"/>
<cim:RemoteUnit.RemotePoints rdf:resource="#00075-30500000-39837340"/>
</cim:RemoteUnit>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-30500000-39837314">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-30500000-39837329">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-30500000-39837339">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-30500000-39837340">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-ArzBZyFrvoWf2ck2Hluuqk">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
<cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-qxB2S9mcOIun9JbjczHdEU">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource><cim:RemoteSource rdf:ID="00075-rPvX1ee3to6MW2M2uE7sNU">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name/>
<cim:RemoteSource.deadband>0</cim:RemoteSource.deadband>
<cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>0</cim:RemoteSource.scanInterval>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMaximum>
<cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>0</cim:RemoteSource.sensorMinimum>
</cim:RemoteSource>
</rdf:RDF>
```